# Giving input such that it reads the exact dataset among the others tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, dataset

I have a certain number of datasets and I've given numbers to each of them as the names let's consider 20 datasets, so the names are 1.csv, 2.csv and so on.

I'm trying to give an input, here the number(name of the dataset) so that my code reads and works on that dataset. How do I make that possible?

I've done something like giving input and changing it into a string and using pandas read_csv(string+".csv") but the code's not working

Can anyone help out?

Comment: What is the error? File not found?

Comment: @Corralien I mean the code is running once in a while like it runs once and doesn't run the next three or four times

Comment: Can you update a relevant part of your code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas read_csv(string+".csv")
I have done this and it works, I had to change the integer to string first.